# what is the best way to test modules in views?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600039/django-view-testing) post, but it didn't contain any relevant answer. 
I am using `Django 1.11` , and my `views.py` is modular (not class based).

I want to test views modules (functions) in the shell, in django's python shell.

```
>>> python manage.py shell
```

By directly importing views like:

```
>>> from my_app import views
```

It works, but this doesn't seem to be preferred way to me.

Is there any preferred way or shall I import views from django in shell or copy the function directly ? What is the best practice for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your going to be much better off just writing Django tests for your views instead of trying to run them from the shell since it will be the same code, but you will be able to easily run the test multiple times.

So to create a test for a single view you would create a tests.py in your django app and write test for the view using django's test client. This test client is a dummy web browser that can be used to make http requests. A simple tests.py would look like this:

```
from django.tests import TestCase, Client

class MyViewsTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client() #This sets up the test client

    def test_my_view(self):
        # A simple test that the view returns a 200 status code
        # In reality your test needs to check more than this depending on what your view is doing
        response = self.client.get('the/view/url')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

you would then run this with the commands `python manage.py test` or `django-admin test` from your terminal

Again you could do this from the shell, but it's going to be better in the long run to use the test framework

Django has some good docs on writing and running tests here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/overview/

and info on the test client along with some other testing tools here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/